# yarn install works but run does not find?

Tags: npm, package.json, yarnpkg

As I have understood the "main" in X's package.json is the file that will be included when you do `require(X)`. However I am getting the error that X could not be included and I need to run `npm install --save X` Which makes sense since `yarn run` calls `npm run`, however yarn does not have a `--save` option. Is there something I am missing?

The package is `jquery-serializeobject`. I can see it present in package.json of the project and in node_modules. The main mentioned in packages JSON exists.

P.S. I am using `yarn` since `npm` does not work, which is a whole other problem

Answer (score 0):

Pfft, I had a typo. No wonder. *facepalm*